# Cakephp Auth and afterFind() in User model

Tags: php, cakephp

Does the Auth component have an afterFind() method on the user model?

Because if I define an afterFind() function in the user model the authentication stops working, it keeps giving me login error.

If I comment the afterFind() function in the user model, the authentication starts working again.

Any ideas?

```
// User.php
function afterFind($results) {

    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {

                if (isset($val['User']['phone'])) {
                    $number = $val['User']['phone'];

                    $results[$key]['User']['phone'] = '(' . substr($number,0,3) . ') ' . substr($number,3,3) . ' - ' . substr($number,6); 
                }

            }

}
```

Comment: I assume `afterFind()` was working before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not [clearly documented](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind), I believe `afterFind()` need to `return` something;

Try placing the following at the end of `afterFind()`:

```
return $results;
```